# Java Heap Size - Young Generation Size without AdaptiveSizePolicy

Tags: java, garbage-collection, heap-memory

today I've noticed a strange behaviour while sizing my java heap. As parameters to size my Young Generation I choose:

```
-XX:NewSize=2100M
-XX:MaxNewSize=2100M
```

Additionally I switched off the AdaptiveSizePolicy with:

```
-XX:-UseAdaptiveSizePolicy
```

According to these 3 parameters my Young Generation should be 2100M the whole time. But when I look into my gc-log the size is just about 1900 MB (~89%). When trying a different size the young generation in the log is around the same percentage (~89%).

The whole heap is 5 GB. In the logfile the size of the whole heap is good (~ 4,97 GB). The Collectors I use are PSYoungGen for Young Generation and ParallelOldGC for Old Generation.

Can someone briefly explain why the young gen size is smaller than it should be?

Comment: Can you post the gc log?

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible you are looking at just the eden space and not the entire young generation?

-XX:NewSize controls '[Maximum size of new generation (in bytes)](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html)' This is not just the 'Eden space', it is also used to manage the two 'Survivor spaces' as well. The ratio between these can be controlled using -XX:SurvivorRatio

See [this link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19159-01/819-3681/abeil/index.html).

For example I am using visualVM with the visualGC plugin installed to examine a java process running with the following VM arguments -XX:NewSize=256M and -XX:SurvivorRatio=4.

[image]

My Eden space is 170.750M
My Survivor 0 is 42.625M
My Survivor 1 is 42.625M

170.750 + 42.625 + 42.625 = 256M

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Maybe you're right, sound logical. But when I've got a logfile-line like "39.910: [GC 39.910: [ParNew: 261760K->0K(261952K), 0.2314667 secs] 262017K->26386K(1048384K), 0.2318679 secs]", I thought the "261952K" in brackets is the size of the whole young generation (eden + 2 survivor spaces). In my logfile this value is different than configurated, e.g. I configured -XX:NewSize=2500M and the logfile says my Young Generation is 2225M (~ 89%)